# spring security customisation

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I would like to be able to change spring security slightly so that the name, email are accessible through the Principal object.

Also to log in I want to user the email and not username.

Where do I start or is this already possible?

Answer (score 1):

Not impossible at all. You need to provide your own implementation of UserDetails though. Its not very difficult at all. [This article](http://www.theserverside.com/tip/-Spring-Security-Customizing-Your-User-and-Authorization-in) shows one possible way to go about doing it. Below are some code that I used recently:

I started by providing my own UserDetails impelementation that suited my purposes. I actually have all the extra details in a Staff class and simply have a Many to One reference from MyUser to Staff. However, I simplified it for this answer and just included the fullName and email properties directly in the MyUser class.

```
public class MyUser implements UserDetails {

  @NotNull
  @Size(min = 3, max = 50)
  private String username;

  @NotNull
  @Size(min = 3, max = 256)
  private String password;

  private Boolean enabled;

  private Boolean accountNonLocked;

  private Boolean accountNonExpired;

  private Boolean credentialsNonExpired;

  private String email;

  private String fullName;

  private GrantedAuthority authorities;


  @Override      
  public Collection<GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
    return authorities;
  }

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return username;
  }

  @Override
public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
      return this.accountNonExpired;
  }

  @Override
public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
      return this.credentialsNonExpired;
  }

  @Override
public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
      return this.accountNonLocked;
    }

  @Override
public boolean isEnabled() {
      return this.enabled;
    }

    public String getEmail(){
        return email;
    }

    public String getFullName(){
        return fullName;
    }
}
```

Then I provided my own User Details Service implementation because I use Hibernate to persist everything in a database. You may need a different implementation:

```
public class MyUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {

  @Override
  public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username)
        throws UsernameNotFoundException, DataAccessException {
      UserDetails userDetails = null;

    TypedQuery<MyUser> q = MyUser
            .findMyUsersByUsernameEquals(username);
    userDetails = q.getSingleResult();
    if (userDetails == null)
       throw new UsernameNotFoundException("user not found");
    return userDetails;
  } 

}
```

Then in the applicationContext-security.xml file I added this:

```
    <!-- Add a custom UserDetailsService -->
<beans:bean id="udservice" class="my.package.name.security.MyUserDetailsService"></beans:bean>
```

and this:

```
<!-- Configure Authentication mechanism -->
<authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">      
    <authentication-provider user-service-ref="udservice">
        <password-encoder hash="sha-256" />     
    </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>
```

Now when you access the user that is logged in you get an instance of your class and access to all its properties.